# How i can erase items from a dictionary that i get from a list

Tags: python

So I was trying to write a code in Python for my homework that I get a list and dictionary from user and erasing items from dictionary that in the list.

```
import ast
a= input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
sample_list=ast.literal_eval(a)
n=list((input().split(",")))

def myFunc(sample_list,keys):
    y=0
        for x in list(sample_list):
            if sample_list[x]==n[y]:
                del sample_list[x]
                    y +=1
myFunc(sample_list,n)
print(sample_list)
```

The code doesn't give me any error but never does the erasing either.

I don't know what to do . I would appreciate any help I can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code has indentation errors. I will assume this is what you meant:

```py
import ast
a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
sample_list = ast.literal_eval(a)
n = list((input().split(",")))

def myFunc(sample_list,keys):
    y=0
    for x in list(sample_list):
        if sample_list[x]==n[y]:
            del sample_list[x]
            y +=1
myFunc(sample_list,n)
print(sample_list)
```

In Python, indentation is used to denote when a scope ends, so it is important that it is correct. Notice how the `for` loop starts at the same indentation level as `y=0` here, unlike in the question.

It's not clear to me what you mean `y` should do. If you want to remove all the keys in the dictionary that also exist in the list, you can do this:

```py
import ast
a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
sample_list = ast.literal_eval(a)
n = list((input().split(",")))

def myFunc(input_dict, keys_to_remove):
    # Loop over all the keys the user named
    for key in keys_to_remove:
        try:
            # Try to remove it. If it does not exist, a KeyError
            # will happen, which we catch.
            del input_dict[key]
        except KeyError:
            # KeyErrors are fine; just ignore them and move on.
            continue

myFunc(sample_list,n)
print(sample_list)
```

Comment: AWESOME!!It solved my problem thank you a lot.I didn't knew about try.I will learn about it more.

Comment: @mehmetenesçetin Glad I could help. It is customary to upvote / accept an answer that is helpful.